# SSHA password encryption on OpenLDAP

Tags: ldap, openldap, sha, ssha

My current problem is that i cannot stop OpenLDAP to store passwords as plaintext. In an older openLDAP version , i entered following configuration in the slapd.conf

```
ppolicy_hash_cleartext
password-hash {SSHA} {SHA}
```

So once a password was sent from my application as plaintext, the ldap was encrypting it and storing it encrypted.

Unfortunately i was not able to configure OpenLDAP 2.4.40. I found out that the slapd.conf does not exist anymore in the newer version and instead the configuration is taking place in the cn=config.ldif file.

I tried to add again the same configuration there but it seems that it has no effect.

**EDIT** : I added with ldapmodify the *olcPasswordHash: {SSHA}* entry in olcBackend={0}mdb.ldif , olcDatabase={1}mdb.ldif , olcDatabase={0}config.ldif and cn=config.ldif , still my passwords that are sent as plaintext are stored as plaintext.

Comment: You 'tried to add the same configuration there' how? Works for me.

Comment: What do you mean it works for you ? Could you describe how you enabled this option ?

Comment: Changing the configuration will only affect passwords that are modified from that point forward. It doesn't affect existing passwords. 'Works for me' doesn't seem obscure to me.

Comment: I am not interested in existing passwords. In my case it does not encrypt passwords of newly created entries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Took some time, but figured out finally.

Load schema describing ppolicy attributes.

```
ldapadd -Y EXTERNAL -H ldapi:/// -f /etc/ldap/schema/ppolicy.ldif
```

Create a ppolicy_module.ldif with the following content and make sure that the ppolicy.la is located under the defined olcModulePath. Store the file under /etc/ldap

```
dn: cn=module,cn=config
objectClass: olcModuleList
cn: module
olcModuleLoad: ppolicy.la
olcModulePath: /usr/lib/ldap
```

Add the ppolicy_module.ldif

```
ldapadd -Y EXTERNAL -H ldapi:/// -f ppolicy_module.ldif
```

Create a ppolicy-overlay.ldif file with the following content. Make sure of the olcDatabase number . In this case it is olcDatabase={1}mdb . Store the file under /etc/ldap

```
dn: olcOverlay=ppolicy,olcDatabase={1}mdb,cn=config
objectClass: olcPPolicyConfig
olcOverlay: ppolicy
olcPPolicyDefault: cn=ppolicy,ou=policies,dc=example,dc=com
olcPPolicyUseLockout: FALSE
olcPPolicyHashCleartext: TRUE
```

Add LDIF file.

```
ldapadd -Y EXTERNAL -H ldapi:/// -f ./ppolicy-overlay.ldif
```

Restart ldap.

More details under:
https://fedorahosted.org/sssd/wiki/openldap_ppolicy

Comment: So you had previously been trying to set `ppolicy` attributes without the `ppolicy` overlay?

Comment: Most probably yes. I am not sure after so many changes i did. I am wondering though who does not like my answer and downvoted. Faq it ! It works.